# set_memory_uc() function of linux API

Tags: linux-kernel

I know some virtual address from user space, I want to uncache the space. I try to use the API set_memory_uc in a kernel module.

I look at the kernel code and found this API accepting virtual address as first argument, but in this API it uses __pa() to convert it to PA. However, __pa() only valid for kernel space virtual address right? So I wonder if I can use set_memory_uc with user space virtual address as argument.

What I expect is a function like :

uncache(VA)   VA is a user space virtual address, this function uncache one page according to the virtual address (I will mlock the page first).

Thank you!

Comment: This is quite old, but I've found that `__pa` is specifically only valid for kernel linear addresses. All logical addresses are virtual addresses, but the inverse is not necessarily true. See [this](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf).